# JColorChooser: hide all default panels and show HSB panel only

Tags: java, swing, jcolorchooser

How can I hide all default panels at `JColorChooser` except **HSB**?

And is it possible to show just HSB without JTabbedPane, just plain panel

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.colorchooser.*;

class ColorChooserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JColorChooser cc = new JColorChooser();
                AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels = cc.getChooserPanels();
                for (AbstractColorChooserPanel accp : panels) {
                    if (accp.getDisplayName().equals("HSB")) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, accp);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try: [`setChooserPanels`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html#setChooserPanels%28javax.swing.colorchooser.AbstractColorChooserPanel%5B%5D%29) method of JColorChooser to do this. More help [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html).

Answer (score 1):

It can be also done with the simple loop:

```
AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels = jColorChooser1.getChooserPanels();
for (AbstractColorChooserPanel accp : panels) {
   if(!accp.getDisplayName().equals("HSB")) {
      jColorChooser1.removeChooserPanel(accp);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete panels you can follow this approach Here I'm removing all the other panels except Swatches and RGB,

```
AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels=colorChooser.getChooserPanels();
        for(AbstractColorChooserPanel p:panels){
            String displayName=p.getDisplayName();
            switch (displayName) {
                case "HSV":
                    colorChooser.removeChooserPanel(p);
                    break;
                case "HSL":
                    colorChooser.removeChooserPanel(p);
                    break;
                case "CMYK":
                    colorChooser.removeChooserPanel(p);
                    break;
            }
```