# How to Enable only RGB tab in JFrame Color Chooser

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

With the JColorChooser created by the following code:

```
        Color newColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(this, "Select Color", Color.yellow);
```

You are presented with the following window:

[image: Color Selection Window]

However, I was wondering if there was a way to only display the RGB tab? as circled here:

[image: RGB tab circled]

Comment: The `showDialog()` method in `JColorChooser` will always show the 5 default chooser panels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JColorChooser: hide all default panels and show HSB panel only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079807/jcolorchooser-hide-all-default-panels-and-show-hsb-panel-only)

Comment: Yes! It does, however I forgot about this question years ago.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Try the following code, removes all but the RGB panel:**

Check the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/colorchooser/AbstractColorChooserPanel.html

```
AbstractColorChooserPanel[] Panels = chooser.getChooserPanels();
for (AbstractColorChooserPanel panel : Panels) {
    System.out.println(panel.getDisplayName());
    String name = panel.getClass().getSimpleName();
    if (!"DefaultRGBChooserPanel".equals(name))
        tcc.removeChooserPanel(panel);
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? How did you know that the name of the rgb panel is `DefaultRGBChooserPanel`? Because I cannot find any class by the name of that in package `javax.swing.colorchooser`