# Can i use swatches panel only

Tags: java, swing, jcolorchooser

I want to use the swatches panel pinned to a toolbar in my original JFrame without having to open a new frame with multiple panels

I tried to remove another taps but still the swatches tap opens on a new frame

```
JColorChooser chooser = new JColorChooser();
AbstractColorChooserPanel[] oldPanels = chooser.getChooserPanels();
for (int i = 0; i < oldPanels.length; i++) {
  String clsName = oldPanels[i].getClass().getName();
  if (clsName.equals("javax.swing.colorchooser.DefaultRGBChooserPanel")) {
    chooser.removeChooserPanel(oldPanels[i]);
  } else if (clsName.equals("javax.swing.colorchooser.DefaultHSBChooserPanel")) {
    chooser.removeChooserPanel(oldPanels[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can... I believe you will be able to do it by following [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079807/jcolorchooser-hide-all-default-panels-and-show-hsb-panel-only).

Comment: @DevilsHnd thank you for you effort but i'd like to use the the swatches pinned to a toolbar like in the microsoft paint app for example
Do you how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
JColorChooser choose = new JColorChooser();
        AbstractColorChooserPanel[] panels = choose.getChooserPanels();
        for (AbstractColorChooserPanel accp : panels) {
            if (accp.getDisplayName().equals("Swatches")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, accp);
            }
        }
```